# gcc 4.7 on Fedora 23 with gcc 5.3.1

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora, fedora-23

I need to install gcc 4.7.x on my fedora 23 in order to make Matlab compile the code. I also came across an error when I was trying to use Cuda which required gcc 4.9.x or lower.

I tried to compile gcc-4.7.4 from scratch but I get the following errors:

```
Makefile:4107: recipe for target 'all-stage1-gcc' failed
make[2]: *** [all-stage1-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/x/src/objdir'
Makefile:19334: recipe for target 'stage1-bubble' failed
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/x/src/objdir'
Makefile:903: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I made a separate directory for configuration and building and I ran the configure as:

```
../gcc-4.7.4/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.7.4
```

However I think the problem rises from the fact that I am using gcc-5.3.1 to compile gcc-4.7.4 but I have no idea how to fix it.

I noticed there is no packages available from dnf to install gcc-4.7.x either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put your build dir inside the source tree. Don't do that. [Follow the wiki's instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC).

> do not run `./configure` from within the source directory, this is not supported. You need to run configure from outside the source directory, in a separate directory created for the build

It'll look something like this:

```
tar xzf gcc-4.7.4.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.7.4
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.7.4/configure --no-multilib --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.7.4 --enable-languages=c,c++
make
make install
```

Comment: I have done exactly the same thing but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little dated now, but patching gcc/cp/cfns.gperf did the trick for me. See here: https://gist.github.com/joka90/bb8ef36aa755994d3b3d/. Built using gcc 5.3.1 under Fedora 23.

```
#Download and apply fix to be able to build gcc 4.7 with gcc 5.1
cd /path/to/build/gcc/source
wget https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/504982/raw/ -O cfns-fix-mismatch-in-gnu_inline-attributes.patch
patch -p1 -i cfns-fix-mismatch-in-gnu_inline-attributes.patch
```

Comment: Links tend to get broken over time. Maybe it would be good if you keep the link but you copy-paste relevant parts to your answer. (In this particular case, maybe all?) Thanks